# Questions about Here map

Tags: android, here-api

My account status for here map is freemium but i have generated APP_CODE and APP_ID successfully but getting  Incorrect application credentials when loading app please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Also please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

For mobile maps you need app id, code and license key. Please follow instructions in https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/README.md to launch your app. Check if you have provided the below details in AndroidManifest.xml file. Also check if the package name provided both while generating credentials and your project matches exactly.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid" android:value="{YOUR_APP_ID}"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken" android:value="{YOUR_APP_CODE}"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key" android:value="{YOUR_LICENSE_KEY}"/>
```